# Function matching in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, mismatch

I have some trouble with Qt.

I have a class 'Core'

```
class Core {

   public:

        static QString get_file_content(QString filename);
        static void setMainwindow(Ui::MainWindow const *w);

   private:
        static MainWindow *main_window;
};
```

and class 'MainWindow' in namespace Ui:

```
namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

In MainWindow constructor I make

```
 MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    Core::setMainwindow(this);
}
```

and gets error

```
mainwindow.cpp:8: error: no matching function for call to 'Core::setMainwindow(MainWindow* const)'
```

Of cource, i include core.h with declaration of 'Core' class.

That's occurs only on setMainwindow method.

So the questions is - why Core class method setMainwindow() is invisible in MainWindow class?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your `Core::setMainwindow` method takes a `Ui::MainWindow*` and you are passing a `MainWindow*`. From the code you posted you have two `MainWindow` classes, one in the namespace `Ui` and one in the top-level namespace. Is this what you mean or should there only be the one in `Ui` perhaps?

Comment: There is one class MainWindow, that declared in Ui namespace. But even if i pass *ui as an argument to setMainwindow i get same error

Comment: @Alexander: Not in the code you've posted. In that code there are two distinct `MainWindow` classes. One is a declaration only of a `MainWindow` class in the `Ui` namespace and the other is a full definition of a `MainWindow` class in the top-level namespace.

Comment: @Alexander: BTW, if you only want one `MainWindow` class then what is the reasoning behind the constructor instantiating another main window? You realise that'll give you an infinite loop that will eventually exhaust memory if you try to run it?

Comment: @alexander: you shouldn't pass *ui as an argument, just ui. then you shouldn't get an error. @Troubadour, there is no infinite loop. The constructor instantiates Ui::MainWindow instead of MainWindow.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add "Core.h" in your MainWindow's cpp/h file ?

Did you try without parameter in setMainWindow, just to check if it's not something related to it ?

Edit : Yeah seems to me you need MainWindow as parameter, not Ui::MainWindow, don't you think ?

Comment: Try and change your MainWindow class's name... Try to remove/change your parameter in your setMainWindow... I'm sure it's something around that...

Answer (score 1):

Your `MainWindow` class isn't nested inside the `Ui` namespace. You forward-declared the `Ui::MainWindow` class, but then implemented a separate `::MainWindow` class (in the global namespace). Because of this, your `Core::setMainwindow` takes a `Ui::MainWindow` but you're passing a `::MainWindow`.

I'm guessing that this lack of nesting is *correct* -- and `Ui::MainWindow` is generated by Qt Designer, and `MainWindow` is the implementation class that contains all of your custom code. If so, change your code to:

```
class Core {

   public:

        static QString get_file_content(QString filename);
        static void setMainwindow(MainWindow const *w);

   private:
        static MainWindow *main_window;
};
```

Comment: That will mean he's left with an infinite loop. But at least it'll compile!

Comment: @Troubadour I don't see any infinite loop here. `Ui::MainWindow` has all of the widgets, but none of the code for how they interact. `::MainWindow` has all of the code for how they interact. It's the standard Qt design pattern when using Qt Designer to draw your interface.

Comment: I was commenting on your initial answer and code, not the version that now appears before me.